# How to perform group by in LINQ and get a Iqueryable or a Custom Class Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, group-by

Here is my query -

```
var data = Goaldata.GroupBy(c => c.GoalId).ToList();
```

This returns a Igrouping object and I want an Iqueryable object which I can directly query to get the data while in this case I have to loop through using a foreach() and then get the data. Is there another way to group by in LINQ which returns directly as a list of Iqueryable or a List as similar to what happens for order by in LINQ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is probably

```
var data = Goaldata.GroupBy(c => c.GoalId).SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
```

In the OO sense they aren't really grouped, but they are ordered with the groups together.

Comment: How to select the top record on the group without converting IQueryable to IEnumerable?

Answer (score 5):

Whilst the accepted answer is correct, it seems to be unnecessarily complicated. Assuming `GoalId` is an `int` you can just use `OrderBy`:

```
var data = Goaldata.OrderBy(c => c.GoalId).ToList();
```

Comment: ya but will that in this case eliminate the entries..I want  to group by as there are multiple entries for same GoalID.? I will try it out though thanks.

Comment: @VJ: OrderBy does not remove any results, it only changes the order.

Comment: IMO this answer is much more simple, in this specific context and will produce the same output as the accepted answer. You have my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Or `.GroupBy(c => c.GoalId).AsQueryable()...`

Comment: Well, this still return an IGrouping item I do it like this
GroupBy(c => c.GoalId).AsQueryable().Tolist()
but doing it as @Stephan  way it works.