# How to get count from two differently grouped iqueryable object in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Currently i am using below query for calculating user activity statistics like, how many times user signing in, signing out etc... Its working fine. But i want to improve my code, by creating the below `UserActivityStatistics` object only once and want to avoid duplicate code & creating object twice as below.

```
    private IList<UserActivityStatistics> ToUserActivityStatistics(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, int pageIndex, int pageSize, Guid userId, ActivityType activity)
    {
        IList<UserActivityStatistics> userActivityStatistics = null;

        if (userId == null || userId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            userActivityStatistics = (from u in SqlGetUserActivityStatistics(fromDate, toDate, userId, activity)
                                      group u by new { u.Activity, u.UserId } into g
                                      select g).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new UserActivityStatistics
                                      {
                                          Activity = Activity.GetActivityTypeName((ActivityType)x.Key.Activity),
                                          ActivityCount = x.Count(),
                                          UserId = x.Key.UserId,
                                          UserName = x.Select(y => y.aspnet_Users.UserProfiles.FirstName + " " + y.aspnet_Users.UserProfiles.LastName).FirstOrDefault()

                                      }).OrderByDescending(y => y.ActivityCount).Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        }
        else
        {

            userActivityStatistics = (from u in SqlGetUserActivityStatistics(fromDate, toDate, userId, activity)
                                      group u by u.Activity into g
                                      select g).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new UserActivityStatistics
                                      {
                                          Activity = Activity.GetActivityTypeName((ActivityType)x.Key),
                                          ActivityCount = x.Count(),
                                          UserId = x.Select(y => y.aspnet_Users.UserProfiles.UserId).FirstOrDefault(),
                                          UserName = x.Select(y => y.aspnet_Users.UserProfiles.FirstName + " " + y.aspnet_Users.UserProfiles.LastName).FirstOrDefault()
                                      }).OrderByDescending(z => z.ActivityCount).Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        }

        return userActivityStatistics;
    }
```

I am improving my code something like below, in that i am moving the `UserActivityStatistics` object outside, and grouping as iqueryable. But i am unable to calculate the count from that iqueryable object. I searched in internet, but i didn't get any solution.

Hope its clear...

```
    private IList<UserActivityStatistics> ToUserActivityStatistics(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, int pageIndex, int pageSize, Guid userId, ActivityType activity)
    {
        IList<UserActivityStatistics> userActivityStatistics = null;
        IQueryable<ActivityLog> activityLog = null;

        if (userId == null || userId == Guid.Empty)
        {

            activityLog = (from u in SqlGetUserActivityStatistics(fromDate, toDate, userId, activity)
                            select u).GroupBy(x => new { x.Activity, x.UserId }).SelectMany(x => x);


        }
        else
        {
            activityLog = (from u in SqlGetUserActivityStatistics(fromDate, toDate, userId, activity)
                            select u).GroupBy(x => new { x.Activity}).SelectMany(x => x);
        }


        userActivityStatistics = (from u in activityLog
                                  select u).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new UserActivityStatistics
                                 {
                                     Activity = Activity.GetActivityTypeName((ActivityType)x.Activity),
                                     ActivityCount = //unable to do count
                                     UserId = x.UserId
                                 }).OrderByDescending(x => x.ActivityCount).Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();


        return userActivityStatistics;
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're grouping and then immediately flattening. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JonSkeet, i am flattening, bcz in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837220/how-to-perform-group-by-in-linq-and-get-a-iqueryable-or-a-custom-class-object) it is mentioned that for returning grouped object in iqueryable we need to do flattening

Comment: Basically, i want to create UserActivityStatistics object only once from the grouped result

Comment: Then you don't want to flatten... you want to project from the group.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting!

Comment: Think about the results of flattening - you lose all the grouping information. You've just got the original sequence in a different order.

Comment: Oh thanks now i am clear about flattening. Actually in that post it was mentioned that "In the OO sense they aren't really grouped, but they are ordered with the groups together", from that i am not clear.

Comment: But, is there anyway to improve my code?

Comment: I don't have time to look at it right now - but certainly it can be improved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur immediate response